# How to install Java on Ubuntu through SSH?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, ssh

In short, all of the installation guides assume that I have a way to download the Java binary. Being clueless, I do not know how to do this.

I'm using Ubuntu 9.10-x86_64

Comment: but you want to SCP the installer and install it?

Comment: @Nishant SCP is just another pile of confusion right now. I'd rather not.

Answer (score 2):

Use `sudo apt-get install <package name>` command

Here is the list of Java packages for Ubuntu 9.10 - http://www.ubuntugeek.com/install-java-runtime-environment-jre-in-ubuntu-9-10-karmic.html

Comment: E: Couldn't find package sun-java6-jre
What did I do wrong?

Comment: try to do `sudo apt-get update` first to update the list of packets. You can also do `sudo apt-cache search java` to find out the list of packets with the word `java` in the name or description

Comment: sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Package sun-java6-jre is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package sun-java6-jre has no installation candidate
What now?

Answer (score 2):

You can use wget from ssh to download a specific file, you can use

```
scp myfile user@host:/path/on/remote/host
```

To copy a file over.

From ssh do

```
scp user@original_host:/path/to/file .
```

To copy a file from a computer to the cwd

Unless you need a specific java version I'd go with

```
sudo aptitude install sun-java6-jre
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning wget and copy over ssh. I prefer rsync, but that will work as well :)

Comment: once again my cluelessness proves fatal. Can I use SCP to grab the file from the website or will I need to put it somewhere acessible? Also: aptitude: command not found

Comment: @Bacu - 'man' is your friend.

Comment: I managed to do it with wget. Wonderful.

Comment: @Bacu - Current versions of Ubuntu no longer have aptitude installed by default, either use apt-get or install aptitude with "apt-get install aptitude"

Answer (score 0):

Try this tutorial for [manual installation of Sun Java runtime](http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=182&t=How_To_Install_Free_PDF_Reader_In_Linux#install_sun_java_runtime_jre_ubuntu_linux). You just need to choose the x64 runtime than the one shown in the screenshot.

Comment: I can't use any sort of browser to get the files.

Comment: @Bacu - Why is that?